# how to make my python project as a software in ubuntu

Tags: python, deployment, pyinstaller

I've made a python program using Tkinter(GUI) and I would like to enter it by creating a dedicated icon on my desktop (I want to send the file to my friend, without him having to install python or any interpreter).

The file is a some-what game that I want to share with friends and family, which are not familiar with coding.

I am using Ubuntu OS.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use `pip3 install pyinstaller` then use `pyinstaller` to convert your file to a .exe file than can run on windows using this command `pyninstaller --onefile -w yourfile`.
it can now run without installing anything on windows. and you can use wine to run it on ubuntu